# Open Source Speech recognition software for search integration

Tags: search-engine, speech-recognition

I have a search application like google search and I need to integrate with voice search facility like google voice search. I am looking for a open source extensible search engine that I can use for the same. I have come across Sphinx4 voice recognition engine and decided to use the same. I would prefer Java with Lucene as a search engine. Has anybody done any of such apps and would like to give me some information on where to start.

Comment: What language, architecture, etc?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you mentioned Google Voice Search: https://github.com/The-Shadow/java-speech-api. It uses the same Speech Recognition Engine. I am sure the rest can be dealt within the Lucene API.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to use Sphinx4 and integrate Lucene search to provide a voice based search solution.

Answer (score 0):

Recently Mozilla announced these two projects:

- [Deep Speech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech)
- [Common voice](https://voice.mozilla.org/data)

The latter has a 12GB data-set for download. The former allows for training a model with your own audio files to my understanding